Send multiple response in a running ussd session
I am trying to build an app that can send a USSD request, read response data (Which is a menu) and then send a response in the session ( eg. an option I would like from the menu). I need to do it multiple times. To make it clear, every response in the session opens a new menu with more options which I need to read in order to find which option I need to enter and then respond with that number.
private void sendCustomFlexi(Context context, String ussdRequest, String offerAmount, String pin) {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try {
            if (tm != null) {
                Class<?> telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());

                if (telephonyManagerClass != null) {
                    Method getITelephony = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    getITelephony.setAccessible(true);

                    Object iTelephony = getITelephony.invoke(tm);
                    Method[] methodList = iTelephony.getClass().getMethods();
                    final Method[] handleUssdRequest = {null}; // Declare as final array to access inside inner class

                    for (Method method : methodList) {
                        if (method.getName().equals("handleUssdRequest")) {
                            handleUssdRequest[0] = method;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (handleUssdRequest[0] != null) {
                        handleUssdRequest[0].setAccessible(true);
                        // 0 for SIM1, 1 for SIM2
                        handleUssdRequest[0].invoke(iTelephony, 0, ussdRequest, new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle ussdResponse) {
                                Object p = ussdResponse.getParcelable("USSD_RESPONSE");
                                CharSequence message = "";

                                if (p != null) {
                                    try {
                                        Method getReturnMessage = p.getClass().getMethod("getReturnMessage");
                                        if (getReturnMessage != null) {
                                            message = (CharSequence) getReturnMessage.invoke(p);

                                            if (message.toString().contains(offerAmount)) {
                                                // Taking the number in front of the offerAmount
                                                String myOfferLine = findLineWithMyOffer(message.toString(), offerAmount);
                                                String numberInFront = extractNumberFromLine(myOfferLine);
                                                handleUssdRequest[0].setAccessible(true);
                                                handleUssdRequest[0].invoke(iTelephony, 0, numberInFront, new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
                                                    @Override
                                                    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle ussdResponse) {
                                                        // Handle the next USSD response
                                                        Object p2 = ussdResponse.getParcelable("USSD_RESPONSE");
                                                        CharSequence message2 = "";

                                                        if (p2 != null) {
                                                            try {
                                                                Method getReturnMessage2 = p2.getClass().getMethod("getReturnMessage");
                                                                if (getReturnMessage2 != null) {
                                                                    message2 = (CharSequence) getReturnMessage2.invoke(p2);

                                                                    // Update UI with next USSD response
                                                                    textViewUssdResponse.setText(message2);

                                                                    // Sending the PIN
                                                                    handleUssdRequest[0].setAccessible(true);
                                                                    handleUssdRequest[0].invoke(iTelephony, 0, pin, null);
                                                                }
                                                            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                handleUssdRequest[0].setAccessible(true);
                                                handleUssdRequest[0].invoke(iTelephony, 0, "99", null);
                                                /*
                                                Repeat checking offerAmount in ussd response. If found, send numberInFront and pin. If not found, send 99
                                                 */
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I tried to do it using handleUssdRequest but every time I send a response in the current session, the USSD menu pops up on the screen. After which it does not take anymore response from app. So I can only send 1 response so far.

Your best bet is to avoid USSD entirely.  It's a legacy protocol, the available codes differ by OEM and carrier, and the OS doesn't really support it.  Even when it kind of does, the user can break it if they install a different dialer app.  The only reason to even consider using USSD is if you're working for a carrier and writing an app for them, and can assure the code will work.  Even then you ought to be moving your backend service to a webservice.

In addition, whenever you see code like this using reflection, it means 1 of 2 things:  either it's written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing, or it's trying to get at private APIs and will be INCREDIBLY brittle and prone to break with even minor OS updates. Calling getITelephony is something that should never be done, because there is no promise that function exists on any other OS version or any other device.

Thank you for your advice. I am now trying to do it using accessibility services
